# Insert array within an array in database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is related to a quiz application. Questions are generated randomly from the database. User selects one answer through radio button. The answer along with question ID and user ID is stored in the database.
Everything is working fine.

The problem is I have an array that I want to store in my database. The following is the code.

The View:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
        <?php $i = 0;
        $ques = 1;
        echo form_open ( 'Menu/submit_ans', array ('name' => 'quiz') );
        foreach ( $quiz_array as $q ) { ?>    
        <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #337ab7; color: white;">
            <h4>Question No. <?php echo $ques?> </h4>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><?php echo $q->ques;?></td>
            <input hidden name="qid[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $q->qid;?>">
            <input hidden name="uid[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $user['id'];?>">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $q->ans_1;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $q->ans_2;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $q->ans_3;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $q->ans_4;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php $i ++;
        } ?>
        </table>
    <center>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit!</button>
        <a></a>
    </center>
</div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**Controller:**

```
function submit_ans() {
    $data = array(
    'qid' => $_POST['qid'],
    'user_id' => $_POST['uid'],
    'ans_att' => $_POST['ans']
    );
    $this->load->model('MyModel');
    $this->MyModel->insert_ans($data);
}
```

**Model:**

```
function insert_ans($data) {
    foreach($data as $answer) {
        //var_dump($answer);
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_answers', $data);        
}
```

Following is the error I get:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_answers` () VALUES ('6','9','1','5','7','10','4','12','8','3','11','2'), ('1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'), Array
```

How can i store the Array into my database?

Comment: use like that `ans['ans_att'][<?php print $i; ?>]` same for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `insert_batch` you must need to use column name as an associative index against each value something like:

```
$data = array( // array structure for batch insert method.
   array(
      'column1' => 'val' ,
      'column2' => 'val' ,      
   ),
   array(
      'column1' => 'val' ,
      'column2' => 'val' ,
   )
);
```

So, what you need here, you need to modify your input fields as:

```
<input type="radio" name="ans['ans_att'][<?php print $i; ?>]" value="4">
```

Same for all other fields as well, above mentioned array is just a hint for your array structure, you must need to modify your array same as mentioned.

You can also debug your `$data` array will help you to understand, what are you doing here, currently your array looks like:

```
$data = array( // structure is not matched with required
    'qid' => some encoded code,
    'user_id' => array(1,1,2),
    'ans_att' => array(1,1,2)
);
```

*Manual will help you to understand more: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html*

Comment: I have dropped the idea of using insert_batch. How can I store all the array values in the database? 

$data =array(
 'q_id' => $_POST['qid'][0],
 'user_id' => $_POST['uid'][0],
    'ans_att' => $_POST['ans'][0]
    );

I want to iterate through array for all the questions and answers and then store them in the database.

Comment: I am trying by setting the same variable in the array for question and answers but I cannot get it to iterate

Comment: Can you please provide any reference? I end up inserting the last value of the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127630/discussion-between-sahib-uz-zaman-and-devpro).

Comment: @SahibUzZaman: if answer work for you dont forgot to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should encode [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method.

Example:

```
<?php 
function submit_ans(){
    $data = array(
    'qid' => json_encode($_POST['qid']),
    'user_id' => $_POST['uid'],
    'ans_att' => $_POST['ans']
    );
    $this->load->model('MyModel');
    $this->MyModel->insert_ans($data);
}
?>
```

and after get record using json_decode();
i hope this code helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store an array in db, convert array to string using 'implode' function

Controller:

```
function submit_ans() {
    $data = array(
    'qid' => $_POST['qid'],
    'user_id' => $_POST['uid'],
    'ans_att' => implode(',',$_POST['ans'])
    );
    $this->load->model('MyModel');
    $this->MyModel->insert_ans($data);
}
```

Simply use insert function in model, no need of insert_batch
Model:

```
function insert_ans($data) {

    $this->db->insert('tbl_answers', $data);        
}
```

Comment: This is letting me store only one value from the quiz. How can I post all the values?